# Add information to badges/{id} method.

Tags: feature-request, badges

Currently, there is no practical way to retrieve badge information given its ID. I would like to see `title` and `description` added at the very least.

Current method for retrieving the data:

- call the `/badges` method
- loop through **every** badge
- at each iteration, check to see if the IDs match

This is inefficient to say the least.

Answer (score 3):

`/badges` returns **every** badge in the system, building a lookup based on id is trivial and costs a single request.

Comment: But fetching the data for *every* badge wastes bandwidth and processing time.

Comment: @George - so, rather than return every badge's description/title once per app run you'd rather see it returned once per call to /badges/{id}?  Your approach wastes much more bandwidth and processing time.

Comment: Uh... given **one** ID of a badge, it would be great if we could get the info for **only** that badge.

Comment: ...or add a filter parameter so that only a particular badge is returned. That'd be good too.

Comment: Anything to avoid iterating over countless badges just to match an ID just to get the description for a badge.

Comment: @George - just build a map from id->description.  O(1) lookup time, one fixed-size request to the API; much better than an unbounded number of requests.

Comment: Kind of tend to agree with George on this one. It would be nice to be able to fetch the info for one particular badge.

Comment: Kevin would have a valid point here if the badges list was **static**, but it isn't.

Comment: @George - the badge page is updated very rarely (order of days), and if you see an id you haven't before, fetch again!

Comment: Yes, I would not mind seeing the other badge routes go away. i cannot think of a compelling use case to dedicate 3 routes for such a low volume of easily discernible data